# Visa requirements for Jamaica for an Indian citizen with a US visitor visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, jamaica

My parents have Indian citizenship and Indian passports. They have US visitor visas and are traveling to US in the next month. I am planning to travel to Jamaica for vacation (5 to 6 days) with my parents.

Is there any specific visa requirements for my parents traveling from US to Jamaica?

In general, I have heard that people with valid Indian passports do not require visas to travel to Jamaica, if the travel is less than 30 days.

Answer (score 6):

### Indian Nationals Get Visa-Free Entry into Jamaica for Stays of up to 30-days

[According to VisaHQ, Indian citizens do not need a Jamaican visa if staying in Jamaica for up to 30 days.](https://jamaica.visahq.com/requirements/India/resident-India/) The immigration officer will stamp the passport upon entry, and the stamp will act as a valid tourist visa. All in all you should just make sure your passport has is valid for more than 6-months after your date of entry in Jamaica, and that you have spare blank pages left. Quoting from the linked website:

> ### Jamaica tourist visa is not required for citizens of India for a stay up to 30 days.
>
> #### First, check the current validity of your passport.
>
> All travelers will need a passport valid for at least 90 days following your departure date from Jamaica. However, we strongly recommend traveling with 6 months validity on your passport at all times. VisaHQ can assist U.S. citizens with a full range of expedited passport services, including new passport application and passport renewal.
>
> #### Second, make sure your passport has blank Visa pages.
>
> Most destinations, including Jamaica, require that you have adequate un-used pages in your passport, allowing for any necessary stamps upon arrival and departure. We recommend that you have at least two free pages in Visas section of your passport before any international travel. U.S. citizens can get extra passport pages added to their passports as fast as within 24 hours.

### What about my US Visitor Visa?

Indeed [Jamaica has a visa-waiver programs for visitors holding US, Canada or Schengen visas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Jamaica#Visa_waiver). These apply to nationals who would usually require a visa to enter Jamaica (for example Peruvian or Paraguayan nationals). Since Indian nationals don't require a visa in the first place then the fact that they hold a US visa has no bearing.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

We are aware of the fact that Indian citizens do not need a Jamaican visa for a stay shorter than 30 days.

But our concern is, whether, this is any different when traveling via the US (with a US visitor visa).

Comment: @JohnSmithSr That shouldn't matter since Indian nationals get visa-free entry to Jamaica, regardless of other visas they might hold. See my updated answer.